# How to get JavaScript variables in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

I builded my own online javascript editor, but when I submit form, javascript not work.
Here are my codes:

editor.php

```
<form action="show.php" method="post" target="window">
HTML code:<br />
<textarea name="html"></textarea><br />
JavaScript code:
<textarea name="javascript"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Test javascript" />
</form>
<iframe src="show.php" width="880" height="600" name="window"></iframe>
```

show.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['html'])) echo $_POST['html'];
  echo "<br><br>";
  if(isset($_POST['javascript'])){
    echo "<script>";
    echo $_POST['js'];
    echo "</script>";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML works well, but when I say something in javascript textarea, javascript will not work in iframe. Please, help me.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: **WARNING!** You're passing unfiltered, unvalidated user input right back out. This can create a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability, easily allowing malicious users to hijack your site for their own purposes.  Hell, you're even doing this *intentionally!*

Comment: I want something like http://jsfiddle.net/ where you can say your HTML and JavaScript code and you can see output

Comment: not going to work unless you do some ajax stuff (if you want it to work it live). You need to send your datas behind the scene , stock them , and when the ajax response returns reload the iframe with new datas. You need to store them serverside somehow.

Comment: Take a look at how sites like jsfiddle.net and jsbin.com do it.

Comment: ok, it works now, I had problem in my PHP code (code what you can not see :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code I see no input field with name `js`, hence I assume the following:

```
echo $_POST['js'];
```

should be:

```
echo $_POST['javascript'];
```

Otherwise, your code should work fine.

Comment: I think @vision is right. I tested your code and it works with this fix. Put an "alert('hello world')" in the JS code and you'll see that it works.